# Showing that $P(AB) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

Proof that $P(AB) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1$

Is this proof sufficient?

By contradiction: Assume $P(AB) < P(A) + P(B) - 1$

if $P(A) + P(B) = 1$, then
$P(AB) < 0$, which contradicts Axiom 1.

Comment: What if $P(A)+P(B)>1$?

Comment: You only considered the case $P[A]+P[B]=1$, so that is not a complete proof. You may want to consider the $P[A \cup B]$ formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq 1 \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \geq \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - 1
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \mathbb{P}(A)\\\\
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \mathbb{P}(B)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \min\{\mathbb{P}(A),\mathbb{P}(B)\}
\end{align*}

Since $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \geq 0$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\max\{\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - 1,0\} \leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \min\{\mathbb{P}(A),\mathbb{P}(B)\}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!